# Why is my password checking code not working correctly? It gives same output regardless of whatsoever input

Tags: c, string, if-statement, nested-if

I made a password checking program which checks for the following criteria:-

- Should have atleast

  - 1 uppercase
  - 1 lower case
  - 1 special character
  - 1 number
- Should be lesser than 100 characters

and thats it. I have not given any lower limit. And no matter what input I give (correct or incorrect), the program gives me the same or similar output as attached in my screenshot.

For eg:- `Pratik10`, `pratik10`, `pratikten`, `pr@tiK10`, I get the same output `"Password is fine and valid"`.

Why is my program not checking the defined conditions correctly? It is not even printing the counters of the password correctly.

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x[100];
    int i;
    int uc=0;
    int lc=0;
    int num=0;
    int misc=0;

    printf("enter your password\n");
    scanf("%s",x);

    for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
        if (isalpha(x[i])) {
            if (isupper(x[i])) {
                uc++;
            }
            if (islower(x[i])) {
                lc++;
            }
        }
        if (isdigit(x[i])) {
            num++;
        }
        else {  
            misc++;
        }
    }

    printf("checking your password\n");
    printf("%d uc\n",uc);
    printf("%d lc\n",lc);
    printf("%d num\n",num);
    printf("%d misc\n",misc);

    if ((uc > 0) && (lc > 0) && (num > 0) && (misc > 0)) {
        printf("password is fine and valid\n");
    }
    else {
        if(lc<=0) {
            printf("lowercase character(s) missing cannot proceed without inclusion\n");
        }
        if(uc<=0) {
            printf("uppercase character(s) missing cannot proceed without inclusion\n");
        }
        if(num<=0) {
            printf("number(s) missing cannot proceed without inclusion\n");
        }
        if(misc<=0) {
            printf("special character(s) missing cannot proceed without inclusion\n");
        }
        printf("please include all the missing parameters in combination to validate the password and try again\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How to correct this?

Output:

[image]

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It will be difficult for others to read your code if you write it like you have did. As for the answer: You can loop until the NUL-terminator as others have said or use `char x[100]={0};`

Comment: @CoolGuy helpfull edits tx. i will indent it now right away

Comment: It's true.  Proper indent will also help to avoid branch judgement logic mistake.

Comment: @CoolGuy is this edit ok? i put in indents with more relevance of loop blocks

Comment: Please do not add pure textual output as an image. Copy the text part into your post.

Comment: @CodeMan Your way of indenting has some mistakes. I would've indented it like [this](http://pastebin.com/uagHV7gH) (link expires in a day)

Comment: @CoolGuy ok i incorporaed these corrections also

Comment: OT: It should better be `scanf("%99s",x);` to avoid overflowing `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check only the null-terminated string provided as input by the user.

In other words, you should iterate `x` until you encounter the null-character.

---

Change this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

To this:

```
for (i = 0; x[i] != 0; i++)
```

---

A second problem is that you are not using `if/else` properly.

As a result, every character which is not a digit is counted as misc.

---

Change this:

```
if (isdigit(x[i]))
```

To this:

```
else if (isdigit(x[i]))
```

Comment: While this is correct, please add explanation on what is happening to help the person

Comment: i tried it, thanks, atleast a major part of code is now working, but now there is another problem, it doesnt count miscellaneous characters. It gives misc = 6 but i havent entered any special characters because my input is pratik10

Comment: @CodeMan , Use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31087105/3049655). Otherwise, `misc` will be incremented if the current character is not a digit.

Comment: @CodeMan, there is a missing `else` before `if (isdigit(x[i])) {num++;}`

Comment: @barakmanos thnx for the correction but can you help me understand that why ;x[i]<100; would not work instead of ;x[i] !=0; what is wrong with that

Comment: @CodeMan: Please read **the first two lines** in my answer. When you obtain user-input with `scanf`, it ends with a null (0) character. So you should only iterate until you encounter this character. You should not continue beyond it, because the remaining part of array `x` is of no importance to you (let alone, uninitialized and contains "junk").

Comment: @barakmanos oh ya, combining your and ammoq answer i got the reason why......also i saw u have combined all the missing answers in comments thanks for that, my essential query solved.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are checking the whole array, which is mostly uninitialized and contains all kind of characters at random.

Therefore, you have to exit the loop when you encounter a `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have mentioned the main problem. There is still one more problem: There is a missing `else` before `if (isdigit(x[i])) {num++;}`,

```
for(i=0; x[i]!=0; i++)
{
   if (isalpha(x[i]))
   {
      if (isupper(x[i])) {uc++;}
      if (islower(x[i])) {lc++;}
   }
   else if (isdigit(x[i])) {num++;} // a missing else
   else {misc++;}
}
```

Comment: @EricTsui yes when i incorporated the correction, it worked thanx, but i did not understand as to why does it need an else and why not just if can do the same. how does this work

Comment: @CodeMan: Without that bugfix, an alphabetic character will be counted twice - once in the `if (isalpha(x[i]))` block, and then again in the `else {misc++;}` block, because it isn't a digit.

Comment: @CodeMan Without `else` here, `misc` will include the `alphabet` letters.

Comment: @ammoQ i get it now, thnx for the quick responses